# Encoding problem when connecting to SQL Server database via odbc_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

Firstly, I don't have an option to use latest SQLSRV drivers on my host so I am stuck with odbc connection.

```
$connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=111.111.111.111;DATABASE=MY_DATABASE';
$user = 'name';
$pass = 'pass';
$connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC );
```

The collation of that database is `Slovak_CI_AI`. If I set my PHP header to utf-8, output data looks messed up, encoding is wrong.

If I put 'Slovak_CI_AI' as a charset to my PHP header, data displays fine, but it is probably a no go, because I need to work with that data in WordPress, which fails to process them if they contain special/non-english characters (those strings looks broken to WP).

I've tried many conversions with mb_convert_encoding, iconv or utf8_decode, but no luck. WordPress uses utf-8.

I can't find any solution for this.

**Update:** I've tried adding `CHARSET=UTF8` to my odbc connection string, but no luck. Also I found out the character set for texts in the database is cp1250. I've tried setting cp1250 as a charset to my PHP header, output is fine but WordPress still fails once it encounters a special character. I've tried converting those strings from cp1250 to utf-8 with iconv, but no luck as well - strings have wrong encoding on output and WordPress fails as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole encoding thing still feels chaotic to me, but I somehow managed to do it. It works when:

- odbc connection string contains `charset=cp1250`
- PHP header character set is set to `utf-8`
- I convert all problematic strings from cp1250 to utf-8 with `iconv`